# What does WebView.flingScroll() do?

Tags: android, android-webview

This link is all the documentation I can find on the [`flingScroll(vx,vy)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#flingScroll%28int,%20int%29) method. It has no description of what the method does.

What does the method do? What are `vx` and `vy`? I was using them as coordinates, but are they velocities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mimics a user flinging the ui. The vx and vy are velocities in the x and y direction (i.e. how fast the user scrolled determines how quickly and how far the view will scroll).

Comment: What are the units of of `vx` and `vy`? px/sec or something similar?

Comment: @Jon Good question. I've never had to achieve that kind of granularity. It may be 1px/sec (or you may be able to convert to that by multiplying by an arbitrary constant).

Comment: So it probably isn't useful for exact positioning then? In what context have you used it?

Comment: If you want something for exact positioning, you'll want to use scrollTo() - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)

Comment: @Jon calling flingScroll is useful if you're handling raw touch events... For example if you need to make a list view that scrolls horizontally.

Comment: I am already using `scrollTo()`. I was curious if `flingScroll()` could be used in a similar fashion but be able to add the fling animation.