# webview does not scroll with flingScroll()

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to scroll the webview after some event occured. so I am calling flingScroll() when some condition is satisfied. but it is not working, webview does not respond at all.

I used scrollby() and it is fixed now.

Comment: what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney I am trying to implement auto scrolling when cursor is on particular area.

Comment: Cursor? What do you mean by cursor?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for flingScroll appears to not really exist.  That sucks. Fortunately you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806587/what-does-webview-flingscroll-do).